# How to write test automation script for single sign on in node

Tags: node.js, testing, single-sign-on

I am aware of jest & supertest frameworks that we can use to write automation test scripts for node backend APIs, but with single sign on there is a UI involved, I can see two possible options to automate single sign on:

1. use UI Test Automation framework such as selenium or playwright
2. try to hack a post request to sso endpoint ( I am not so sure if this will work )

Is there any other way through which we can test SSO from the backend ?
or should SSO be a part of UI automation test cases ?

Comment: SSO does not require a UI.

Answer (score 1):

Using a UI (SSO with redirect) is not the only way to generate a token for your API calls.

For example if you are using `OAuth 2.0` use [Client Credentials grant type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/) to just generate your token (instead of [Authorization Code grant type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/) that depends on a redirect link)

Check your SSO providers and its protocols to find a method that doesn't involves UI to generate a token.